# Change default mapping of string to "not analyzed" in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, elasticsearch-mapping

In my system, the insertion of data is  always done through csv files via logstash. I never pre-define the mapping. But whenever I input a string it is always taken to be `analyzed`, as a result an entry like `hello I am Sinha` is split into `hello`,`I`,`am`,`Sinha`. Is there anyway I could change the default/dynamic mapping of elasticsearch so that all strings, irrespective of index, irrespective of type are taken to be `not analyzed`? Or is there a way of setting it in the `.conf` file? Say my `conf` file looks like

```
input {  
      file {
          path => "/home/sagnik/work/logstash-1.4.2/bin/promosms_dec15.csv"
          type => "promosms_dec15"
          start_position => "beginning"
          sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
      }
}
filter {

    csv {
        columns => ["Comm_Plan","Queue_Booking","Order_Reference","Multi_Ordertype"]
        separator => ","
    }  
    ruby {
          code => "event['Generation_Date'] = Date.parse(event['Generation_Date']);"
    }

}
output {  
    elasticsearch { 
        action => "index"
        host => "localhost"
        index => "promosms-%{+dd.MM.YYYY}"
        workers => 1
    }
}
```

I want all the strings to be `not analyzed` and I don't mind it being the default setting for all future data to be inserted into elasticsearch either

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can query the `.raw` version of your field.  This was added in [Logstash 1.3.1](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/logstash-1-3-1-released/):

> The logstash index template we provide adds a “.raw” field to every field you index. These “.raw” fields are set by logstash as “not_analyzed” so that no analysis or tokenization takes place – our original value is used as-is!

So if your field is called `foo`, you'd query `foo.raw` to return the `not_analyzed` (not split on delimiters) version.

Comment: the foo.raw fields are empty while the foo fields are filled. I don't get it

Comment: @Roland Kofler Did you find out why they were empty?. I have the same issue

Comment: @AviArro all I can remember it is intended that way. Sort of a hack. More I can't remember

Comment: Is it a given that everyone with this question will be using logstash?

Comment: @JonCrowell well yes and no. I stumbled back on my answer the other day when NOT using logstash. I couldn't rind the `.raw` field and realized it was something logstash created for me, so my answer here was not helpful.  :) However, the question is tagged and refers to logstash, so makes sense that my answer is the accepted one.  There are other related SO questions and answers about creating `not_analyzed` fields with vanilla Elasticsearch that can be referred upon.

Comment: Logstash `5.x` with Elasticsearch `5.x` changes the mapping from `.raw` to `.keyword` - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#_template_management_for_elasticsearch_5_x

Answer (score 28):

Just create  a template. run

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_template/template_1 -d '{
    "template": "*",
    "settings": {
        "index.refresh_interval": "5s"
    },
    "mappings": {
        "_default_": {
            "_all": {
                "enabled": true
            },
            "dynamic_templates": [
                {
                    "string_fields": {
                        "match": "*",
                        "match_mapping_type": "string",
                        "mapping": {
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "omit_norms": true,
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "properties": {
                "@version": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "geoip": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "dynamic": true,
                    "path": "full",
                    "properties": {
                        "location": {
                            "type": "geo_point"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Comment: What exactly does this *do*?  How does it *work*?  Can you elaborate a bit more on what this template is and how it applies to the question?

Comment: @Brad as you can see here, inside `dynamic templates` and `properties`, the `index` is set as `not analyzed`. As a result, if we input a string `hello, I am Sinha` it will be treated as one string and not split into `hello` `I` `am` `Sinha`

Comment: what is the index name that this mapping applies to?

Comment: it applies to all indices @AbtPst

Comment: ok, that makes sense. what if i only want to apply to some fields of an index. lets say i have an index `ind`. the number of fields in the incoming data is not fixed but for sure there will be a string field`d`. I only want field `d` to be analyzed and all other string fields to be not analyzed.

Comment: @SagnikSinha what exactly your are doing to drop ".raw" fields of each fields? Did you mean dropping "fields" parameter in mapping file will drop ".raw" part of each field and save 50% of space? I do have mapping file in which I do have "fields" parameter for each field I am extracting out of log.

Answer (score 13):

Make a copy of the lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-template.json from your Logstash distribution (possibly installed as /opt/logstash/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-template.json), modify it by replacing

```
"dynamic_templates" : [ {
  "string_fields" : {
    "match" : "*",
    "match_mapping_type" : "string",
    "mapping" : {
      "type" : "string", "index" : "analyzed", "omit_norms" : true,
      "fields" : {
        "raw" : {"type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed", "ignore_above" : 256}
      }
    }
  }
} ],
```

with

```
"dynamic_templates" : [ {
  "string_fields" : {
    "match" : "*",
    "match_mapping_type" : "string",
    "mapping" : {
      "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed", "omit_norms" : true
    }
  }
} ],
```

and point `template` for you output plugin to your modified file:

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    ...
    template => "/path/to/my-elasticsearch-template.json"
  }
}
```

You can still override this default for particular fields.

Comment: That doesn't seem to give me desired results... I have a field named `State` which has an instance called `West Bengal`. When I plot a bar graph, I get 2 different legends namely `west` and `bengal` which is wrong. That problem is still there

Comment: Is this in a new index? Keep in mind that changing the index template won't make a difference for existing data.

Comment: I deleted the previous index, refreshed it and then inserted again. Yes, its in a new index

Comment: Interesting. What if you [get the mapping of the index](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html) and have a look at the actual mapping being used?

Comment: It shows 
`{"promosms-16.12.2014":{"mappings":{"promosms_dec15":{"properties":{..............,"State":{"type":"string"},.........}}}}}`

there is no information as to whether it is analyzed or not

Comment: I declared the whole thing as a template and it worked. I set `"template" : "*"`

Answer (score 1):

I think updating the mapping is wrong approach just to handle a field for reporting purposes. Sooner or later you may want to be able to search the field for tokens. If you are updating the field to "not_analyzed" and want to search for foo from a value "foo bar", you won't be able to do that.

A more graceful solution is to use kibana aggregation filters instead of terms. Something like below will search for the terms ivr04 and ivr02. So in your case you can have a filter "Hello I'm Sinha". Hope this helps.

[image]