# elasticsearch not reading .raw fields in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am revisiting elasticsearch | logstash | kibana after a long time and trying the new versions. Setup turned out to be effortless but after a day of working well, I tried to access my dashboard and it could not locate the dashboard, saved searches etc. I then restarted elasticsearch and started over but now I do not see the .raw fields in drop down menus to add visualizations. 
How did this happen?

I found some posts that suggested removing all old indices and restarting as elasticsearch will do this as a default but that did not work.
Even in the discover tab the .raw files are not visible.

I may as well ask this as well; how did the dashboard and search history all just disappear at some point. Also I am running elasticsearch, kibana, logstash on one server as the data I am indexing is low volume.
Any suggestions appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: figured this out by deleting the index the third time and changing the template file as suggested here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27483302/change-default-mapping-of-string-to-not-analyzed-in-elasticsearch/27502037#27502037