# Where do .raw fields come from when using Logstash with Elasticsearch output?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

When using Logstash and Elasticsearch together, fields with `.raw` are appended for analyzed fields, so that when querying Elasticsearch with tools like Kibana, it's possible to use the field's value as-is without per-word splitting and what not.

I built a new installation of the ELK stack with the latest greatest versions of everything, and noticed my `.raw` fields are no longer being created as they were on older versions of the stack.  There are a lot of [folks posting solutions of creating templates on Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27502037/362536), but I haven't been able to find much information as to *why* this fixes things.  In an effort to better understand the broader problem, I ask this specific question:

**Where do the .raw fields come from?**

I had assumed that Logstash was populating Elasticsearch with strings as-analyzed and strings as-raw when it inserted documents, but considering the fact that the fix lies in Elasticsearch templates, I question whether or not my assumption is correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're correct in your assumption that the `.raw` fields are the result of a dynamic template for string fields contained in the default index template that Logstash creates IF [`manage_template: true`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-manage_template) (which it is by default).

The default template that Logstash creates (as of 2.1) can be seen [here](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-elasticsearch/blob/b85e72e8c160100a84a6ebc341fda88f58de0999/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-template.json). As you can see on line 26, all string fields (except the `message` one) have a `not_analyzed` `.raw` sub-field created.

However, the template hasn't changed in the latest Logstash versions as can be seen in the [`template.json` change history](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-elasticsearch/commits/b85e72e8c160100a84a6ebc341fda88f58de0999/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-template.json), so either something else must be wrong with your install or you've changed your Logstash config to use your own index template (without `.raw` fields) instead.

If you run `curl -XGET localhost:9200/_template/logstash*` you should see the template that Logstash has created.

Comment: Thank you.  Unfortunately, no template is created in Elasticsearch at all, and definitely not one named `logstash`.  I tried specifying a local one in my Logstash config, and that hasn't worked either.  But, your information gets me closer to the problem and clarifies things.  I'll keep digging!

Comment: Weird. So you confirm that you have ES 2.1 + Logstash 2.1 installed, right?

Comment: Logstash `2.1.0`, and Elasticsearch `Version: 2.1.0, Build: 72cd1f1/2015-11-18T22:40:03Z, JVM: 1.7.0_91`  I tried editing that `elasticsearch-template.json` and specifying the path to the new JSON file, setting all string fields to `not_analyzed`, nuked all my indices in Elasticsearch and ran Logstash again.  That made no difference, strings were still analyzed and no raw fields created.

Comment: Can you update your question with your elasticsearch output config?

Comment: I'll post a new question and link you to it in a minute, so as not to get this one off topic. However, the only output configuration specifies the elasticsearch host.  I experimented with adding the new template but it made no difference.  `output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ['localhost:9200']
  }
}
`

Comment: Good move, I was going to suggest ;-)

Comment: For some reason, manually putting it into Logstash worked for me.  It didn't work when I specified it in the config, nor by default like it probably should have, but using curl to `PUT` it up to Logstash solved my problem.  No idea what the root problem was, but perhaps I'll mess with it another day to reproduce.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Ok, I'm glad you figured it out. Feel free to come back with more details later if needed.