# Logstash (2.4.0) and Elasticsearch (2.4.1) missing .raw fields

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I am a newbie to ELK and just found the raw fields missing from Elasticsearch as showed in Kibana below,

[image: kibana data fields]

I checked Logstash data mapping as below,

[image: Logstash mapping]

and the simple Logstash configuration,

[image: Logstash configuration]

Could someone please shed a light on how to make both analysed and non analysed fields available?

Thanks, 
Sean

Comment: solving the issue by change manage_template to true. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33979226/where-do-raw-fields-come-from-when-using-logstash-with-elasticsearch-output