# logstash date filter unable to convert field to date type

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I am facing issues while converting a text field to date with date filter. Here's the logstash code I am using:

```
grok {
       patterns_dir => ["/etc/logstash/conf.d/patterns"]
        match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_DD_MM_YYYY:start_date}%{SPACE}%{TIME:zimbra_proc_start_time}%{SPACE}%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:log_level}%{DATA}%{DAY:day}%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA}\n%{DATA}\n%{DATA}\n%{TIMESTAMP_DD_MM_YYYY:end_date}%{SPACE}%{TIME:zimbra_proc_end_time}" }
    }

    mutate {
      add_field => {
        "end_date_parse" => "%{end_date} %{zimbra_proc_end_time}"
        "start_date_parse" => "%{start_date} %{zimbra_proc_start_time}"
      }
    }

    date {
      match => [ "start_date_parse", "HH:mm:ss", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", "dd MMM yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", "d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss" ]
      target => "zimbra_proc_start_time"
    }

    date {
      match => [ "end_date_parse", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", "HH:mm:ss", "dd MMM yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", "d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss" ]
      target => "zimbra_proc_end_time"
    }

    mutate {
      remove_field => "end_date_parse"
      remove_field => "start_date_parse"
    }
```

Also, there's no _grokparsefailure or _dateparsefailure in sight. So, date is being parsed correctly but the type is still being reported as keyword in ES.

Comment: It might be a mapping problem on the elasticsearch side: in ES, the fields `zimbra_proc_***_time` are already mapped as keyword.

Comment: @baudsp How can I fix that? At the moment, I am manually setting the desired date type in new index and then reindexing the old log which reports this as keyword and then delete the old index. This is definitely not a good solution.

Comment: You'll have to create a new template in elasticsearch and specify it in your elasticsearch output. To create it: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/27502037/6113627, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/indices-templates.html. Then when specifying the index in your elasticsearch output, chose a name matching the pattern from the template.

Comment: But I haven't done this in quite some time, so you should take a look at the documentation to see if I haven't written a mistake.